# Ruby on Rails: need to log data on a daily basis (hosted on Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Cronjob vs Scheduler for Heroku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you just need a periodic task to run once per day. The currently recommended way to do that at Heroku is to use the [scheduler add-on](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler):

> Scheduler is an add-on for running jobs on your app at scheduled time intervals, much like `cron` in a traditional server environment.
>
> A dashboard allows you to configure jobs to run every 10 minutes, every hour, or every day, at a specified time. When invoked, these jobs will run as one-off processes and show up in your logs as a process named run.N.

The basic process is pretty simple:

1. Set up a Rake task to do whatever it is you need to do:

   ```
   desc "This task does ..."
   task :your_task => :environment do
       # Do something interesting...
   end
   ```
2. Add the scheduler add-on in the usual manner:

   ```
   $ heroku addons:add scheduler:standard
   ```
3. Then add your new Rake task through the Heroku dashboard.

If you want to run your periodic task outside Heroku then set up a cron job to run the appropriate Rake task.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to put this task into a Cron job which handles recurring processes or tasks.

Here is an excellent screencast on the subject courtesy of Ryan Bates:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby-revised

---

If you need to set up recurring jobs on Heroku, you need only add your tasks to `lib/tasks/scheduler.rake` and configure them using the Schedular Add-on

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler

Comment: @Ringo: It will if you make a `lib/tasks/cron.task` and configure the cron add-on, however the cron add-on is deprecated in favor of the scheduler add-on.